# how to create single instance of jersey Client for multiple request

Tags: rest, jersey, java-6, jersey-client

Hi I am here using jersey.1.19.1 API Client for Rest full web service.
I came to know that creating an instance of Client is an expensive.

As I am creating instance of it every time i call the web service, 
response is delayed which it leads affecting the performance.

So is there any other way in creating instance of Client for multiple request.
and also how to over come in delay even for creating single instance of a Client

Is it a right approach to create a Client object pooling as that of connection pooling or one Client object for one user. Even is there any other best way for creating Client object

Answer (score 0):

As there is no much info provided to have a clue on your structure, something along these lines will help

1. Create an instance variable of the jersey client

   ```
   private Client client = null;
   ```
2. In a method that returns `client`, check if that field is null, if it is initialise it, otherwise return same instance

   ```
   if(client == null)
       client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

   return client;
   ```